# How can I correct this error with AWS CloudFormation template

Tags: aws-cloudformation

Team, I'm stressing out because I cannot find the errors with the following JSON script I'm trying to run in AWS Cloudformation; I'm receiving the following error:

(Cannot render the template because of an error.: YAMLException: end of the stream or a document separator is expected at line 140, column 65: ... e" content="{"version": "4", "rollouts& ... ^

<meta name="optimizely-datafile" content="{"version": "4", "rollouts": [], "typedAudiences": [], "anonymizeIP": true, "projectId":

Please help!!!

Comment: Welcome to SO. We'll definitely need some more information. First, try to copy/paste the *entire* error message. And second, try and give us more lines of your template; note the line numbers (and if possible, give us the entire template)

Comment: Is there a way to give you upload the JSON file as an attachment?  It's pretty long.

Comment: If it's *really* long you could put it in something like jsbin.com and share the link to that. If it's only moderately long, use a code block here in SO

Comment: Here's the link https://jsbin.com/bujalecusa/edit?html,output

Comment: What is that? We need to see the "JSON script" you are trying to run in Cloudformation. The actual template file you are trying to upload to Cloudformation. That's not JSON, that's html.

Comment: Here's an example of a Cloudformation template written in JSON: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cloudformation-templates/blob/master/community/services/VPC/vpc_template.json

Comment: jsbin.com doesnt give you an opten to create a json script

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Ok, without seeing the JSON you are trying to upload to CloudFormation, it's unlikely anyone is going to be able to help. You should be able to put the JSON into the javascript section of jsbin